# Performance boost for a web service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, asynchronous, ado.net

I have a situation where I'm calling a web service and it can take 2 to 3 minutes to save an image in the database. It's a straight forward call, no tricks, etc. I have no idea what the other web service is doing other than saving the image to a database.

The thing is, that there will be fuel tickets flowing into into **my** web service where I need to call the **above** web service to save the image.

I have no control of making the web service **that saves the image** an asynchronous call.

Would it be enough if I increase the max pool size on my connection string coming into my web service, where the requests just get queued up, eventually calling the other web service and saving the image or will some kind of timeout occur with the fuel tickets that are coming into my service to wait for the other web service to save the image?

Can I do anything on my side to help increase the performance?

Comment: If it's that slow I would look at taking the call out of process of your web API. I've had good luck with WCF and MSMQ to create a message queue system. Then you can have a windows service or another app call the slow service. You can look into a service bus also if you need it but usually a message queue works well. Downside you won't get feedback if something fails on the service side since it's like a fire and forget on your web API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ThreadPool to queue up the work and then receive more requests

```
 ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((callback) =>
 {
      //Call service here
 });
```